# Why do I get the different result when calling export command?

Tags: shell, command

Recently, I am trying coding on Ubuntu 22.04.
And, I wrote a text file which is shown below.

```
---- Start of export.txt ----

export WORKSPACE=$PWD

---- End of export.txt ----
```

Then, I use the command below to execute it.

```
$source export.txt
```

After that, running another command to build my personal code.

```
$source buildsetup.sh // WORKSPACE will be used in this sh file
```

However, it will complain no WORKSPACE is defined.

And, If I execute "export" directly in the command shell.

```
$export WORKSPACE=$PWD
```

Then, run the same command

```
$source buildsetup.sh
```

Then, everything goes well.
Could anyone teach me the difference between them?

Comment: With all the unnecessary `*`s and `$`s in your commands, it's hard to tell *what* you are actually executing.

Comment: Sorry, those *s should be removed. And, $ means the shell.

Comment: How, *exactly*, does `buildsetup.sh` use `WORKSPACE`? [mcve], please.

Comment: <pre>
if [ $WORKSPACE ] ;then
  echo $WORKSPACE
  if ( command -v $WORKSPACE >/dev/null 2>&1 );then
    return 0
  else
    echo $WORKSPACE Cannot be used to build
    return 1
  fi
fi
<code>

The code snippet is as above.

Comment: What do you expect `command -v $WORKSPACE` to do? `command` does `PATH`-based command lookup; a directory is not a command.

Comment: I just test if the WORKSPACE can be shown anywhere. The problem is when I do "source test.sh", the first echo can show WORKSPACE but in the else, show nothing.
I can't understand why it happens.

Comment: What is `test.sh`? Please edit all the relevant information into an [mcve] in the *question* itself; don't add code to the comments.

Comment: The test.sh is 
--------------------------------
 if [ $WORKSPACE ] ;then 
   echo $WORKSPACE 
   if ( command -v $WORKSPACE >/dev/null 2>&1 );then return 0 
   else 
      echo $WORKSPACE Cannot be used to build return 1
   fi 
fi
--------------------------------